# Multiplication Explicit Casting not working C

Tags: c, casting, explicit

```
long long int calculateUnits(int tokenVal, int billVal, int numOfTokens, int numOfBills)
{
    long long int units;

    // tokenUnits = billVal * numOfTokens;
    // billUnits = tokenVal * numOfBills;
    units = (long long int)(billVal * numOfTokens) + (long long int)(tokenVal * numOfBills);

    // return number of units
    return units;
}
```

For small numbers this works fine. But as soon as the multiplication outcome gets big enough, I start getting negative numbers. I thought the explicit casting would solve the issue.

Am I using it wrong, or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
(long long int)(billVal * numOfTokens)
```

This doesn't mean "treat both these as if they were `long long int`", it means do the multiplication using their *actual* types, then upgrade the *result* to `long long int`. The multiplication, and therefore any overflow, is done *first.*

What you need to do is force one of the variables to be the wider type (the other will be implicitly upgraded) so that the multiplication uses the wider type:

```c
(long long int)billVal * numOfTokens
```

---

However, a better solution, since you want to work with the wider type, may be to use that wider type in the function signature:

```c
long long int calculateUnits(long long int tokenVal, long long int billVal,
    long long int numOfTokens, long long int numOfBills)
{
    return billVal * numOfTokens + tokenVal * numOfBills;
}
```

That way, you don't need to worry about casting, the variables will implicitly be upgraded to the wider type as part of the function call, and your code becomes more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying ints returns an int. If the result is too large for an int, it overflows and you get implementation-dependent behavior.

You should cast one of the parameters to `long long`, then the result will be `long long`. Casting the result doesn't work, because that does the conversion after the overflow has already occurred.

```
units = ((long long int)billVal * numOfTokens) + ((long long int)tokenVal * numOfBills);
```